# SSIS package failing on first run because of to many rows of data

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package that I am trying to run but it always fails because of buffer to much data. This is on my first run. I then thought I should only grab my data from todays date and 30 days and do that insert. My question is how would I then grab the date for that last 30 days then do it again for the next 30 days and again until I have all the data inserted into my data warehouse?

my query looks like this

```
SELECT db_name() dbname,  TicketType, TicketNo source_bk, UniqueID, ItemNo, CASE WHEN  VehicleID  = '' THEN '-1' ELSE VehicleID END VehicleID 
, CASE WHEN  TicketID  = '' THEN '-1' ELSE TicketID END TicketID,
 case when p.purchaseOrder = '' then 'unknown' else p.PurchaseOrder end as PurchaseOrder, TicketDate, TicketTime, S1.LocationID
, S1.CustomerID, S1.OrderID, OrderItem, ProductID, MixID, S1.TaxCodeID,  S1.CarrierID,  Description, DeliveryAddress1
,  Gross, Tare, Net, Qty, Unit, FreightQty, FreightPayQty, S1.Price, S1.FreightRate, S1.FreightAmount,  S1.FreightPay
, FreightPayAmount, TodayLoads, TodayQty, OrderLoads, OrderQty,  AltTicketQty, AltTicketQtyEdited, TodayAmount
, 'Posted' as [Source] FROM tkhist1 S1  WITH (NOLOCK)
join [dbo].[Slordnam] p 
on s1.customerID = p.CustomerID
where s1.TicketDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -30
UNION
SELECT db_name() dbname,  TicketType, TicketNo source_bk, UniqueID, ItemNo, CASE WHEN  VehicleID  = '' THEN '-1' ELSE VehicleID END VehicleID 
, CASE WHEN  TicketID  = '' THEN '-1' ELSE TicketID END TicketID,
 case when p.purchaseOrder = '' then 'unknown' else p.PurchaseOrder end as PurchaseOrder, TicketDate, TicketTime, S1.LocationID
, S1.CustomerID, S1.OrderID, OrderItem, ProductID, MixID, S1.TaxCodeID,  S1.CarrierID,  Description, DeliveryAddress1
,  Gross, Tare, Net, Qty, Unit, FreightQty, FreightPayQty, S1.Price, S1.FreightRate, S1.FreightAmount,  S1.FreightPay
, FreightPayAmount, TodayLoads, TodayQty, OrderLoads, OrderQty,  AltTicketQty, AltTicketQtyEdited, TodayAmount
, 'Posted' as [Source] FROM Tkbatch S1  WITH (NOLOCK)
join [dbo].[Slordnam] p 
on s1.customerID = p.CustomerID
where s1.TicketDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -30
UNION
SELECT db_name() dbname,  TicketType, TicketNo source_bk, UniqueID, ItemNo, CASE WHEN  VehicleID  = '' THEN '-1' ELSE VehicleID END VehicleID 
, CASE WHEN  TicketID  = '' THEN '-1' ELSE TicketID END TicketID,
 case when p.purchaseOrder = '' then 'unknown' else p.PurchaseOrder end as PurchaseOrder, TicketDate, TicketTime, S1.LocationID
, S1.CustomerID, S1.OrderID, OrderItem, ProductID, MixID, S1.TaxCodeID,  S1.CarrierID,  Description, DeliveryAddress1
,  Gross, Tare, Net, Qty, Unit, FreightQty, FreightPayQty, S1.Price, S1.FreightRate, S1.FreightAmount,  S1.FreightPay
, FreightPayAmount, TodayLoads, TodayQty, OrderLoads, OrderQty,  AltTicketQty, AltTicketQtyEdited, TodayAmount
, 'Posted' as [Source] FROM Tkscale S1  WITH (NOLOCK)
join [dbo].[Slordnam] p 
on s1.customerID = p.CustomerID
where s1.TicketDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -30
```

after it got done inserting these I would want it to do this again on the next run but get the next 30 days from the end of this. So what I already have is because this data is coming from many databases I have a for each loop and doing this for each database. I want it to get 30 days from now then do the process over and over for the first run because I can't get it to run at all as it is. Then I would do a CDC to only do new data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two answers to consider...

One is, what do you mean "to much data" - SSIS doesn't have a limit on how much data you want to put through a dataflow. Are you saying the server can't handle the query or you are trying to say do a lookup in SSIS and running out of memory or something else?  Bottom line is, it sounds like you might be wise to approach this in a different way since there should be no such limitation.

Two is, if you really want to process sets of rows at a time, make your query dynamic and do a For Loop saving incrementing your date range 30 days for every loop. You can create dynamic SQL in a number of ways and those methods depend on what type of connection you are using and what method you prefer as they all have pros/cons. The most flexible and consistent way which works with any relational connection is to create a string variable and set it's value based on a vbscript.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hey I thank you for your answer. What happened is I inherited an SSIS package that someone else created and they said it worked already but when I tried to run it... it never worked; however, you are right i shouldn't of had a problem so what I did was tore it down and rebuilt it.and now it is working fine.